# Nginx log rotation is happening without any file in logrotation.d

Tags: logging, nginx, log-rotation

I just compiled and installed nginx in RPM based Linux. Noticed that log rotation of Access logs and error logs are taking place. but there is no file in `/logrotation.d/` which operated on the directory `/var/log/nginx/` .

I need to change the file name format of the archived logs, but as there is no file in logrotation.d, dont know what to change.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: On Ubuntu it's access.log access.log.1 access.log.2.gz access.log.3.gz access.log.4.gz access.log.5.gz and so on.

Comment: Yes on Ubuntu there was no issues. But here its access.log-20120521.gz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some default policy of nginx. Just create an entry in logrotation.d it will override.